# update date value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert date format in ORACLE SQL Developer

The current format is yyyy/mm/dd-hh:mm:ss:sss and I need to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss CST
I don't really know SQL but did some research.
Here is the command that I consultanted other people on the forum. but it throws me unrecognized command error. table name is B and column name is First

```
UPDATAE B
set First = concat(to_char(substring(FIRST,1,4) + '-' + substring(FIRST, 6, 2) + '-' + substring(FIRST, 9, 2) + ' ' + substring(FIRST, 12, 8));
```

Could anyone here help me with it? thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a typo there (UPDATAE?). You are also just setting one text field to another. Where is the date?

Comment: If the column is a `DATE` column it does not have "a format". You don't need to UPDATE the table. Just use a different format when *selecting* from the table. If the column is not a `DATE` column then you should change your design. Do not store dates in `varchar` columns.

Answer (score 1):

The "unrecognized command" is merely a misspelling of `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATAE B

// Should be
UPDATE B
```

To verify the result is what you expect before executing the `UPDATE` statement, use a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
  to_char(substr(FIRST,1,4) || '-' || substr(FIRST, 6, 2) || '-' || substr(FIRST, 9, 2) || ' ' || substr(FIRST, 12, 8)) AS Test
FROM B
```

Comment: thanks , that was a silly misspelling, i execute your command and it shows invalid number of arguments now :(

Comment: by the way, what does this column point to in the error message?
Error at Command Line:1 Column:7

Comment: @user1200687 Whoops see changes above. I had just modified your original statement, but realize now it wouldn't work properly for Oracle. The `concatenate()` shouldn't have been there at all, and all the `+` should have been `||`

Comment: so apprently substring don't work for oracle too?
i got this now ,Thanks for the help again.
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: i changed everything to substr, but still doesn't work :(, same error

Comment: @user1200687 With `SUBSTR()` (sorry I didn't catch that) you might now have an issue with the fact that I aliased the whole expression `AS First`. Take off the alias at the end, or as I did above, change to `AS Test`.

Comment: @user1200687 Phew..! glad you got it sorted out. I'm out of practice with Oracle's idiosyncrasies, as I've been spending all my time with MS SQL & MySQL lately.

Comment: i know, they are confusing. This is my first time doing sql stuff, it's actually really fun,lol. alright, have a great night and weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

Umm... I'm either missing something extremely obvious or everyone else is.

You want to date operations? Use `to_date` and `to_char`. I'm going to assume this `ss:sss` means, seconds, then fractional seconds. You date appears to be a string so we need to convert it twice:

```
update b
   set first =  to_char( to_date( my_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd-hh:mi:ss:ff3')
                        ,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss' )
```

Generally, when using dates it's far, far easier to only use [date functions](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html) and the provided [formats](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-fmt.html).

As an added point if you have a date, store it as a date. It'll save a world of bother later on.