# Update Oracle timestamp to current date

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, sql-update

I have a TIMESTAMP(6) field in Oracle db. Value of this field is in format

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.000000000 PM
```

How to update this value to the current timestamp?

[a link to a similar question:] [update date value in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337935/update-date-value-in-oracle)

I followed this link, but following query is taking very long time to execute.

```
update table_name set start_time = to_char(to_date(start_time, 'yyyy/mm/dd-hh:mi:ss:ff3'), '2012/10/10-19:30:00:00') where column='Q'
```

Answer (score 23):

A [timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref158) is a point in time, it has no format. To update such a field to the current timestamp, use [`SYSTIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions192.htm#SQLRF06125) or [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions045.htm#SQLRF00629) (respectively the date/time of the server and the date/time of the session):

```
UPDATE your_table 
   SET your_column = systimestamp
 WHERE ...
```

If the query takes an abnormal amount of time (much longer than a comparable SELECT with the same WHERE clause), the mostly likely causes are:

1. The rows that your are updating are locked by another session (doing a SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT on these rows will make sure that *you* have the lock).
2. You have triggers that perform additional work,
3. You're updating a column referenced by a  non-indexed foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't just

```
update table_name 
set start_date = systimestamp 
where column='Q'
```

If you suspect there are locks on the table, there are some tables to check: `dba_locks`, `v$session`, `v$session_blockers` etc. These are useful when a user blocked something with an accidental `update` without a `commit` or `rollback`, but you should be able to see if can exists blocking locks from the architecture of your application. You should just simulate on paper all the scenarios.

Comment: Surprisingly this command never returns. Initially I thought its problem with Sql Developer. So I tried in sqlplus command line. It behaves same. Any clues please?

Comment: @sandyr commit/rollback or kill all the sessions that have a lock on the rows of this table.

Comment: if there are few rows `where column='Q'`, then @VincentMalgrat is right, there is a lock on those rows. If the table is Very Big and the number of rows affect is considerable, you shoud wait. Oracle must write data on disks. This don't just happen.

Comment: A program polling table continuously looking for records to be processed. 

I think this program is locking entire table. Which system table stores info if its doing row level locking or table locking?

Comment: There are some tables: dba_locks, v$session, v$session_blockers etc.